# Show and Hide child objects along with Parent

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I have several Parent objects that each have a lot of child objects. I need to key frame showing/hiding the various different stacks of objects at different points without it becoming too tedious. Ideally, i'd like it if I could set my child objects to share the show/hidden status of the parent object. Is this possible?

Alternatively, is there a way to keyframe the show/hide of a whole selection of objects at once?

Comment: I think, easiest way to do this - scale parent down to 0 in one frame.

Comment: As a comment, as I've no idea how it was done. I've seen something like that done through drivers. Alternatively, have one .blend for the object groups (each parent with its children as a group), and a second .blend for the animation, where you link to the *groups* in your first .blend (used as a library)?

Comment: This is a render time consideration, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**, much better way to do this using properties

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147144/15543

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197072/15543

**Fudge the driver system 2.9x**

I removed the previous answer re doing this in 2.8, don't really recommend this one..

[Melodicpinpon asks](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214875/15543)

> Would it work in 2.9 version? This question has been debated in many
> places and this method could be the solution...

[image]

Using a method somewhat similar to [@AtomicBezierSlinger](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104540/15543) can add a driver to every object in the scene that has a parent.

However the use of use self makes this driver readily copy pastable into other objects, without the need to check or set the parent object.

Here is a test script to add the driver to all objects with a parent.

```
import bpy

from bpy.app import driver_namespace as dns

def test(self, dg):
    vl = dg.view_layer
    return not self.parent.original.visible_get(view_layer=vl)
 
dns["test"] = test
   
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
#parented objects
parented = [o for o in scene.objects if o.parent]

for o in parented:
    #o.animation_data_clear() # testing
    #continue
    o.animation_data_create()
    fcurve = o.driver_add("hide_viewport")
    driver = fcurve.driver
    driver.expression = "test(self, depsgraph)"
    driver.use_self = True
    # dummy var to make driver update.
    var = driver.variables.new()
    var.name = "dummy" # frame
    var.targets[0].id_type = 'SCENE'
    var.targets[0].id = scene
    var.targets[0].data_path = "frame_current"
```

Making a test method and adding to the driver namespace is unnecessary as it can be directly crunched into expression field as

```
not self.parent.original.visible_get(view_layer=depsgraph.view_layer)
```

use self is not default and will need to be set.

---

answer below is for versions prior 2.8 with the use self option available.  Also not a recommended way to use driver system.

---

**Fudge the driver system**

Firstly we'll set up a custom driver that sets a property of all children recursively to the value of the parent.

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

def set_children(obj, prop):
    val = getattr(obj, prop, None)
    if val is not None:
        for c in traverse_tree(obj): 
            setattr(c, prop, val)       
    return val    

bpy.app.driver_namespace["setchildprops"] = set_children
```

Now we can add a driver to a custom property on the same object as the property we wish to set on all children.

```
setchildprops(self, "hide")
```

making sure to check the non default "use_self" property of the driver.

[image]

Now if you keyframe the "hide" property of the same object it will hide / show children accordingly.  Note it will not update the UI automatically, until some property eg frame is updated.

Comment: Anyone tried this with 2.82 too?

Answer (score 1):

- Consider a driver which copies the Render Visibility value of the parent.  This will be successful.
- The objects will still be available for [3D View Window] viewing.  Only you can determine if this arrangement  suits you.
- You might even copy the [3D View Window] visibility based on the Render Visibility of the parent or any other object.
- Please click on the image below to see a larger image.

---

[image]

---

- The purple color on the visibility settings indicates a script.  The eye dropper was used for the target ... the parents render visibilty.  Arrow indicates the driver.
- Consider the copy and paste of drivers from the context menu.
- The contents of the driver are shown in the graph drivers pane.
- You might even consider layer visibility to avoid clutter.
- If you have a simple still shot ... you can move objects off the viewable area.  This idea is for simple circumstances only.