# toggle hide/unhide parent and children objects at once similarly to the outliner Shift+LMB function

Tags: python, scripting, objects, parent

Is it possible to simulate the `Shift+LMB` for hiding a parent object with its children as in the outliner. Now based on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180142) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/151270/106722) I am iterating over the children objects and hide_set(True) them individually:

```
def toggle_hide (list, mode=True):

    children_list = []    
    for obj in list:
        if obj.children:
            children_list.append(obj.children)

        obj.hide_set(mode)

    if children_list:
        for child in children_list:

            toggle_hide (child)

bpy.data.objects["parent"].hide_set(True)
toggle_hide(bpy.data.objects["parent"].children)
```

`bpy.data.objects["parent"].hide_set(True)` hides only the parent object leaving the children unhidden, which I need to do it afterwards recursively.

My guess is that under the hood might be the same procedure that is happening but I was wondering if someone can just call the corresponding outliner build in function instead of re-implementing it or by passing some flag to the [`hide_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=hide_set#bpy.types.Object.hide_set) though as I see it takes only a `view_layer` id.

---

Update (not working):

Now I want to add the solution from @batFINGER to a class, e.g.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

class Utility:

    class AddHidingProperty:
        def __init__(self):
            bpy.types.Object.hide_children = BoolProperty(update=self.hide_children)
            
            bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.append(self.draw)
        
        def hide_children(self, obj, context):
            obj.hide_set(obj.hide_children)
            for o in obj.children:
                o.hide_children = obj.hide_children
        
        # function to draw the checkbox in the editor footer      
        def draw(self, obj, context):
            layout = obj.layout
            ob = context.object
            layout.prop(ob, "hide_children")
```

However when I call the `Utility.AddHidingProperty()`, this gives me the following error: `ValueError: bpy_struct "Object" registration error: hide_children could not register`.

---

Update 2 (working):

The following seems to work but I am not sure whether it is a good approach:

```
class Utility:

    class AddHidingProperty:

        def __init__(self):
            
            def hide_children(obj, context):
                obj.hide_set(obj.hide_children)
                for o in obj.children:
                    o.hide_children = obj.hide_children
                    
            # function to draw the checkbox in the editor footer      
            def draw(obj, context):
                layout = obj.layout
                ob = context.object
                layout.prop(ob, "hide_children")
                
            bpy.types.Object.hide_children = BoolProperty(update=hide_children)
            
            bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.append(draw)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Define and toggle a boolean property**

From the other answer to link https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147144/15543 it gives the object a `hide_children` property that if set hides the object and sets `hide_children` hence setting recursively for all children.

A checkbox to set the property is added to the text editor footer for testing.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty


def hide_children(self, context):
    self.hide_set(self.hide_children)
    for o in self.children:
        o.hide_children = self.hide_children


bpy.types.Object.hide_children = BoolProperty(update=hide_children)


def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    ob = context.object
    layout.prop(ob, "hide_children")


bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.append(draw)
```

Since the object can be found from context, can toggle the boolean value of the property using the window managers context toggle operator

After you have run the script above to register the property on the Object class

```
>>> C.object.hide_children
False

>>> C.object.hide_children = True

>>> bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(
context_toggle()
bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="", module="")
Toggle a context value
>>> bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="object.hide_children")
{'FINISHED'}
```

If You do not run the script beforehand will get an error

```
# same as not running script (unregister the property)
>>> del bpy.types.Object.hide_children 
>>> bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="object.hide_children")
context_path_validate error: context.object.hide_children not found (invalid keymap entry?)
{'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

**Assign a shortcut.**

With the script above run, and the property defined  can be set as a shortcut from context.

[image]
*Image of `Edit > User Preferences > Keymaps`*

Since once hidden an object cannot have context, and from the 3d view there is no way to select as a group <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> will unhide all previously hidden objects.

Note both the object (`self`) and context is passed to the update method could instead hide all objects and their children looping over `context.selected_objects`

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand that much of what you are doing there :-(. Could you explain a bit more. I was checking on your answer on the other thread as well but I couldn't figure out how to pass a specific parent object as input to `hide_children()`. You create this boolean property but how do I call/toggle it for a parent object. Also does the object needs to be selected first each time or I can call it by the name? If you don't mind I would appreciate if you could please provide a calling example. Btw I've run the script but I cannot see any window manager context toggle operator...

Comment: ...if I run `bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="object.hide_children")` I am getting `{'PASS_THROUGH'}` instead of {'FINISHED'} as in your case.

Comment: See edit. Run the script first.  The method fires when the property of an object is updated.  The object is the owner of the property `self` in the update method. Blender's context operator paradigm rarely passes an object to a method, instead operates on context

Comment: Appreciated thanks a lot, I got it now.

Comment: one more question I want to add the code snippet above within an existing class as a subclass, however I am getting an error `ValueError: bpy_struct "Object" registration error: hide_children could not register`. Check on my update section, in the initial post.

Comment: The update method is going to be incorrect. It is expecting a method with 2 arguments, whereas `self.hide_children(context)` in this case has one, with self being an instance of your class. One way would be to define `def hide_children(self, ob, context)` making the distinction that when used as an update property the `ob` is the object.

Comment: But then I would need to pass each object `ob` individually or not? I do not get it.

Comment: `AddHidingProperty.hide_children` is a method definition that has two arguments, whereas in the init method `self.hide_children` is a method with one, eg if you were to call it it would be `self.hide_method(context)` because it belongs to the class instance the self is implied by the owner. Because `self.hide_render` only has one argument it fails to register.  Use either `update=hide_render` or `update=AddHidingClass.hide_render`.  This is basic python class method stuff.  If you use with `ob` as suggested, then `self` is your class, and `ob` will be treated as the object with the property

Comment: being updated. The method assigned to an update function is required to have 2 arguments, which it would since you would call it from `__init__` (for example) using `self.hide_render(ob, context)` ie a method that takes two arguments. If you don't need to discern between your class instance and the object instance, don't do it this way.\  You are going to have issues with draw next for same reasons....

Comment: Ok, I was really confusing the `self` class instance with `self` object with the property. I've updated the code with the suggested `def hide_children(self, ob, context)` approach. I still get the error though.

Comment: Yep, bum steer, lol... should have checked.  Notice the error `TypeError: update keyword: expected a function type, not a method`  In python a function defined on a class is a method.  Hence the registration error.  Printing `self.hide_children`  ...> `<bound method Utility.AddHidingProperty.hide_children of <__main__.Utility.AddHidingProperty object at 0x7f658bb72fa0>>`  This makes sense since could del that class instance but the object would still be looking for an update method.  Your last edit is using the function def, and hence is Ok.

Comment: I'll keep the solution in update 2 for now. It seems to do the job, though I am not sure whether it is the proper approach. Thanks a lot.